# Selective and Specific printing of hash Map key - value pairs

Tags: java

While writing test automation, i was required to leverage the api's provided by the developers and these api accepts HashMap as arguments. The test code involves calling several such api with hashmap as the parameter as shown below.

```
 Map<String,String> testMap = new HashMap<String,String>();



setName()
{
   testMap.put("firstName","James");
   testMap.put("lastName","Bond");
   String fullName=devApi1.submitMap(testMap);
   testMap.put("realName",fullName);
}

setAddress()
{
  testMap.put("city","London");
  testMap.put("country","Britain");
  testMap.put("studio","Hollywood");
  testMap.put("firstName","");
  testMap.put("person",myMap.get("realName"));
  devApi2.submitMap(testMap);
}
```

However the requirement was to print the testMap in both setName and setAddress functions, but the map should print only those elements (key-value pairs) in alternate lines which are set in the respective function. I mean setName should print 2 elements in the Map which are set before submitMap api is invoked and similarly setAddress should print 5 elements which are set before submitMap is invoked.

setName Output must be:

```
  The data used for firstName is James. 
  The data used for lastName is Bond
```

setAddress Output must be:

```
 The data used for city is London.
 The data used for country is Britain.
 The data used for studio is Hollywood.
 The data used for firstName is null.
The data used for person is James Bond
```

Any help, in order to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write a helper function that would add items to the map and do the printing.

```
public static <K,V> void add(Map<K,V> map, K key, V value){
  System.out.println(String.format("The data used for \"%s\" is \"%s\"", key, value));
  map.put(key, value);
}
```

If you need to print different messages you could either use different helper functions or pass format string as an argument.

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thanks for the reply. yeah i can write a different helper, but the problem is while priniting. so if i print the testMap for the first time it should print only 2 elements as in setName() method and printing the testMap for the second time it should print only 5 elements as entered in setAddress() method. But when the testMap is printed it is printing 2+5 = 7 elements and that is the problem.

Comment: @SriramDharmapuri You could use what SiB recommends, but I like it less because test setup code and printing code can end up not in sync. You'd have to remember to update printing code each time you change anything. If you use this `add` method it will automatically print only those items that you add, nothing else.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. I will try as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method which takes a **comma separated list** of keys as argument and print only them.

Something like:

```
 public void printKeys(Map<String,String> map, String csKeys) {

      for(String key: csKeys.split(",")){
           if(map.conatinsKey(key)){
               System.out.println("The data used for " + key + " is " + map.get(key) );
           }
      }
 }
```

and you can invoke it like:

```
printKeys(testMap, "firstName,lastName");
printKeys(testMap, "city,country,studio");
```

Comment: I think accepting variable number of strings is a bit cleaner: `public void printKeys(Map map, String ... keys){for (String key : keys){}}`.

Comment: Hi SiB. Thanks a lot for the reply. is it possible for the printKeys method to read all the keys automatically, rather than asking the user to hand code all the keys with comman separation.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create a copy of your `testMap` when you invoke the `submitMap` method, since you don't have a flag to indicate which key-value pairs should be printed.

You could do it like

```
Map<String, String> printObj = new HashMap<String, String>

setName()
{
   testMap.put("firstName","James");
   testMap.put("lastName","Bond");
   String fullName=devApi1.submitMap(testMap);
   printObj.addAll(testMap);
   testMap.put("realName",fullName);
}
```

Then print the `printObj` instead of `testMap`.

Comment: Or another way, to create a POJO class, which has a value field to save your values(name information, address information, etc), another boolean field to indicate whether the field should be printed or not. And change the flag in your 'submitMap' methods.

Answer (score 0):

From you comments on my earlier answer it seems you don't want the values put from one method to be displayed in the second one...

That can be done easily, just place:

```
testMap.clear();
```

in the beginning of every method.